# Propagating succulents in 3 months, is it possible?

Tags: succulents, propagation

I'm planning to give succulents as wedding gift. I need more than 300 succulents in small size (5.5 cm pot) I want to propagate them myself, I believe it will be more precious than just buying from a garden.

So is it possible to propagate succulents from leaves in 3 months in 2-3 cm height? I've started to propagate, but the process seems slow. Is it possible to make it fast? For example using rooting hormone, some fertilizer vs.

I don't know the exact names of my plants but I've started a month ago now they are very little:

[image]

I've just made them for test. Now I will mass produce with lots of leaves. The progress seemed too slow, so I thought that do I need some fertilizer, hormones vs

Comment: 3 month might be enough, depending on the succulent. My bet is temperature and air moisture are the key. What kind of succulent is it? You would be welcome to illustrate your question it with a picture.

Comment: I don't know the exact names of my plants but I've started a month ago now they are very little: http://2.1m.yt/mWJCNTP.jpg I've just made them for test. Now I will mass produce with lots of leaves. The progress seemed too slow, so I thought that do I need some fertilizer, hormones vs.

Comment: Cute little ones! I added them to your post, to illustrate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a gardener's perspective, the problem is that you can't "speed up" something that needs a certain time to grow - too much fertilizer, for example, could even kill your babies. So apart from creating *optimal* conditions, there isn't much you can do. And you might want to id your parent plants first (hint: this site specializes in such questions), to find out what the best conditions for cuttings are.

But let's do some math here:
If you planted a month ago, I guestimate it took at least two weeks for the roots and first leaves to start to form. In another two months, you'll certainly see more growth.

If you are planning to give succulent favours like in the photo below, you might be a bit short on time, but trying certainly won't hurt.

[image]

[Source](http://celsiafloral.com/journal/2015/3/18/west-coast-wedding)

My very pragmatic suggestion: 
Get the cuttings started asap, then if in *two* months your *test* batch is still way too tiny, you have a full month to order bigger plants in time for the wedding. Also, start more than the number of plants you need, I'd probably start with 20% or so more, especially if you have different types, that might grow at different rates.

And - not gardening-related - you can always add a little note to your (too) tiny plants explaining that they are as new as your new marriage bond and need time and care to grow, just like your marriage. Thank your guests for caring for you and supporting you in the future.

Answer (score 1):

[50 succulents for 35 bucks](https://www.etsy.com/listing/230300335/set-of-50-succulent-cuttings-succulent?utm_campaign=shopping_us_CoronaSucculents_sfc_osa&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_custom1=0&utm_content=7494383&gclid=CJfc07aC4dMCFdKFfgod97MMOw)Where are you starting these succulents? Greenhouse, out of doors? What a perfectly wonderful idea! Even the little starts you have NOW are good enough for little gifts but in 3 months, they will be better rooted, established. Do NOT try to fertilizer or add anything you thing will hurry them along. A LITTLE fertilizer is fine but VERY LITTLE. Use a NPK formulation with extended release...4- 5- 6. Or close % #'s Just a tiny bit to help the roots grow before the top growth. TINY. Make a little card to explain the proper care to go with. Sweet!

Your expectations are another thing.  This will be a bit of work but 'lots of leaves' might not be what you imagine and I imagine.  One thing you should check into would be purchasing already made baby plants from a wholesale nursery.  Do you have any contractor friends with resale cards?  That would save lots of money.  Your contractor friend might know the wholesale nurseries.  I'd expect around $1.00 per plant this size already cute.  These succulents are slow growing.  I've seen 'Hens and Chicks' look great in 3 months but there are extenuating circumstances that could ruin your expectations.

Check out Park Seeds, Territorial Seeds, Wholesale plants on the internet.  This would be far easier and surer than doing this yourself.  Otherwise look forward to 3 months of worry.  If this is one month's growth which looks very healthy and normal, then 3 more months...???

I would try to see what you could find on line for sure. [wedding succulent gifts](https://www.google.com/aclk?sa=l&ai=DChcSEwjo9cPMgOHTAhWGYH4KHX8GAdgYABANGgJwYw&sig=AOD64_27GwguBxQvpfS5MGHfirr4nWqW9g&adurl=&ctype=5&q=&nb=9&res_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsearch.yahoo.com%2F&rurl=https%3A%2F%2Fsearch.yahoo.com%2F&nm=12&is=428x408&nx=41&ny=20&clkt=192&bg=!Dg2lDRVE4T69cbSLSmQCAAAAeFIAAAAZCgA5ofJiyFgdPIZ_eLulYhYUDlt8b7lOnp4GR86XLUZ_onm-8Ls77IHnEy0z-eBUxblCW42jch6t12LbmQDwONOhad2YmyCqG-G6miEkmSDJLJ8r1lPlhsl9aFh-K7W3WptgEsJaKTGP3HmjBN3LYDaUck9Ew_YEz5sOVmw56KyFbXmFQBWAl11gxm14y8QmiN_hTsvMc6x_bBNkOFWqu4bmyVOEMJsUkw7r4qWDQ77A6irxoyLfMBM7nWQseKnaihcojcqDXKJlK5-fY9yUhkee4cRd9acko4I3hw_2QAXJO1d2lSrA6r7xI9QM0Gs1YNGU73MKYBTBZsD0NWhbZ5VWEJZWNqQBOtN1peKnYIGEeCS2VUfEXwalmEv3wNSeIFH2pE8GXr6YoZjXz6VQ)  Not as inexpensive as I thought.  But still affordable considering this includes perfect little specimens, pots and soil.  Hope this helps.

This is another idea where you have to pot them up but they come fully cute.[Succulent starts](https://img0.etsystatic.com/055/0/7494383/il_570xN.759512516_8mqk.jpg) [50 starts for 35 bucks](https://www.etsy.com/listing/230300335/set-of-50-succulent-cuttings-succulent?utm_campaign=shopping_us_CoronaSucculents_sfc_osa&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_custom1=0&utm_content=7494383&gclid=CJfc07aC4dMCFdKFfgod97MMOw)